# Ignoring absolute values in differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3y - 1}{x}$. It is separable and we get $\ln|3y - 1| = C + \ln(|x|^3)$. On wolfram the solution is reported as $y(x) = c_1 x^3 + \frac{1}{3}$ but wouldn't this ignore solutions like $y(x) = \frac{|x|^3 + 1}{3}$?

Answer (score 2):

Your differential equation is not defined in $x=0$ (division by zero). So the solution can only be defined on two disjointed intervals, $x>0$ and $x<0$. Since the two intervals are disjoint, you can choose a different constant on both sides.

Your solution $y(x)=\frac{|x|^3+1}{3}$ corresponds to the Wolfram solution but with $c_1=1$ on the right and $c_1=-1$ on the left.

PS : however, you can stitch the solution on $\mathbb{R}^-$ and $\mathbb{R}^+$  to get a continuous solutions on $\mathbb{R}$. However, you can still choose the two integration constants arbitrarily.